# Any API to get the data on the query DAG from Spark UI SQL tab

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-ui

The spark UI has an SQL tab. It can show the query detail as a DAG

```
https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/operation_spark_applications.html
```

After the application finishes, the DAG also annotates its nodes with statistic information. For example,

```
number of output rows: 155,418,058

peak memory total (min, med, max): 
24.1 GB (704.0 MB, 704.0 MB, 704.0 MB)

aggregate time total (min, med, max): 
15.6 m (20.8 s, 25.5 s, 42.1 s)

Exchange data size total (min, med, max): 
1350.1 MB (2.2 MB, 2.3 MB, 2.3 MB)
```

Does Spark have any API to fetch the metics? Spark has https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#executor-task-metrics accessed by RESTful APIs. And the stage tab on Spark UI also shows "Summary Metrics" of each task. However

1) I am not sure how to relate task ID to RDD or nodes on a query DAG

2) the Peak Execution Memory metric is always 0, while as we can see the SQL tab can show

```
peak memory total (min, med, max): 
24.1 GB (704.0 MB, 704.0 MB, 704.0 MB)
```

The other question is how to read the metrics on DAG nodes. For example,

```
peak memory total (min, med, max): 
24.1 GB (704.0 MB, 704.0 MB, 704.0 MB)
```

Is min, med, max for a node? Its value is much smaller than the total 24.1G ...